# Typesetting a crossword puzzle in LaTeX

Tags: rules, line, puzzle

I've been trying to typeset a simple crossword in a nice way in LaTeX, using the [cwpuzzle package](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/gene/crossword/cwpuzzle.pdf), but I keep having issues.

Namely, lines around the cells seem "doubled" or overlapping.

What could I do in order to fix that?

**Here's my code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[large]{cwpuzzle}
\renewcommand{\PuzzleBlackBox}{\rule{.45\PuzzleUnitlength}{.45\PuzzleUnitlength}}
\renewcommand{\PuzzleLineThickness}{.5pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{Puzzle}{16}{16}
    |{} |{} |{} |[5]D   |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |[15]W  |{} |{} |.
    |{} |{} |[6]B   |E  |A  |U  |T  |I  |F  |U  |L  |{} |{} |I  |{} |{} |.
    |{} |{} |{} |L  |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |T  |{} |{} |.
    |{} |{} |{} |[1]A   |B  |A  |N  |[2]D   |O  |N  |{} |{} |{} |H  |{} |{} |.
    |{} |{} |{} |Y  |{} |{} |{} |I  |{} |{} |{} |[16]L  |I  |O  |N  |{} |.
    |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |G  |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |U  |{} |{} |.
    |{} |{} |[3]C   |R  |E  |A  |T  |E  |{} |{} |{} |[12]C  |A  |T  |{} |{} |.
    |{} |{} |O  |{} |{} |{} |{} |S  |{} |{} |{} |U  |{} |{} |{} |{} |.
    |{} |{} |L  |{} |{} |{} |{} |T  |{} |[13]G  |I  |R  |A  |F  |F  |[17]E  |.
    |[14]B  |R  |O  |W  |N  |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |R  |{} |{} |{} |L  |.
    |{} |{} |M  |{} |{} |{} |[9]D   |[8]I   |M  |I  |N  |I  |S  |H  |{} |E  |.
    |{} |{} |B  |{} |{} |{} |{} |N  |{} |{} |{} |C  |{} |{} |{} |P  |.
    |{} |{} |U  |{} |{} |{} |{} |S  |{} |{} |{} |U  |{} |{} |{} |H  |.
    |[7]D   |I  |S  |A  |P  |P  |E  |A  |R  |{} |{} |L  |{} |{} |{} |A  |.
    |O  |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |N  |{} |{} |{} |U  |{} |{} |{} |N  |.
    |G  |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |E  |{} |{} |{} |M  |{} |{} |{} |T  |.
\end{Puzzle}


\begin{PuzzleClues}{\textbf{Across}}
\Clue{1}{ABANDON}{ABANDON}
\Clue{3}{CREATE}{CREATE}
\Clue{6}{BEAUTIFUL}{BEAUTIFUL}
\Clue{7}{DISAPPEAR}{DISAPPEAR}
\Clue{9}{DIMINISH}{DIMINISH}
\Clue{12}{CAT}{CAT}
\Clue{13}{GIRAFFE}{GIRAFFE}
\Clue{14}{BROWN}{BROWN}
\Clue{16}{LION}{LION}

\end{PuzzleClues}

\begin{PuzzleClues}{\textbf{Down}}
\Clue{2}{DIGEST}{DIGEST}
\Clue{4}{COLOMBUS}{COLOMBUS}
\Clue{5}{DELAY}{DELAY}
\Clue{8}{INSANE}{INSANE}
\Clue{10}{CURRICULUM}{CURRICULUM}
\Clue{11}{DOG}{DOG}
\Clue{15}{WITHOUT}{WITHOUT}
\Clue{17}{ELEPHANT}{ELEPHANT}

\end{PuzzleClues}

\clearpage

\PuzzleSolution

\begin{Puzzle}{16}{16}
    |{} |{} |{} |[5]D   |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |[15]W  |{} |{} |.
    |{} |{} |[6]B   |E  |A  |U  |T  |I  |F  |U  |L  |{} |{} |I  |{} |{} |.
    |{} |{} |{} |L  |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |T  |{} |{} |.
    |{} |{} |{} |[1]A   |B  |A  |N  |[2]D   |O  |N  |{} |{} |{} |H  |{} |{} |.
    |{} |{} |{} |Y  |{} |{} |{} |I  |{} |{} |{} |[16]L  |I  |O  |N  |{} |.
    |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |G  |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |U  |{} |{} |.
    |{} |{} |[3]C   |R  |E  |A  |T  |E  |{} |{} |{} |[12]C  |A  |T  |{} |{} |.
    |{} |{} |O  |{} |{} |{} |{} |S  |{} |{} |{} |U  |{} |{} |{} |{} |.
    |{} |{} |L  |{} |{} |{} |{} |T  |{} |[13]G  |I  |R  |A  |F  |F  |[17]E  |.
    |[14]B  |R  |O  |W  |N  |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |R  |{} |{} |{} |L  |.
    |{} |{} |M  |{} |{} |{} |[9]D   |[8]I   |M  |I  |N  |I  |S  |H  |{} |E  |.
    |{} |{} |B  |{} |{} |{} |{} |N  |{} |{} |{} |C  |{} |{} |{} |P  |.
    |{} |{} |U  |{} |{} |{} |{} |S  |{} |{} |{} |U  |{} |{} |{} |H  |.
    |[7]D   |I  |S  |A  |P  |P  |E  |A  |R  |{} |{} |L  |{} |{} |{} |A  |.
    |O  |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |N  |{} |{} |{} |U  |{} |{} |{} |N  |.
    |G  |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |{} |E  |{} |{} |{} |M  |{} |{} |{} |T  |.
\end{Puzzle}


\end{document}
```

**And here's what the result looks like:**

[image]

Comment: The “doubling” has to do with how cells are stacked together. I'm not sure there's a way to remove them.

Comment: The example on page 6 of the manual also seems to have some thick lines, as well as the Kakuro example on page 12.

Comment: I had the same problem until I print my page. If you print your page, you will see that they disappear. I think it's due to the PDF viewer.

Comment: It's probable that this package was created when the primary output was to be printed on paper, not viewed onscreen.  The effect is much less obvious on printed output, where overlaid rules don't result in a double layer of toner.

Comment: It was likely due to how this particular PDF viewer rasterized the image. Try viewing the graph at different zoom to see if the doubling changes.